# Getting errors in JavaScript used by StackOverflow controls

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

I cannot use stackoverflow.com. The JavaScript which controls the user interface is not loaded from the server completely. In Firefox Console I see:

```
Timestamp: 13.07.2012 17:29:43
Error: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
Source: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=b5c180f15a74
Line 167, Character 443
Source code:
e[0].substr(1),d=b+d,f=d-e.length;return c&&/@[^\s!?();:+"]/.test(a.substr(0,f-1))?null:{start:f,pos:b,end:d,name:e}}function c(b){var a=d();if(a.name===b)l.is(":focus")||l.focus();else{var c=l.val();l.val(c.substring(0,a.start)+b+c.substring(a.end));b=a.start+b.length;l.caret(b,b)}}function b(b){var a;if(9==b.which){a=$("#tabcomplete li");if(!a.length)return;var d=a.filter(".chosen").removeClass("chosen"),d=b.shiftKey?d.prev():d.next();d.
```

Not working top-left popup menu with notifications, not working upvote button, not working "accept answer" checkbox.

I have tried reloading the page with F5. Nothing. It doesn't work on Chrome either.

Comment: Did you try CTRL+F5 in case you have a corrupted file in your cache?

Comment: It helps me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have a corrupted file in your cache. Use <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd> to refresh everything without using the cache.

Another option would be clearing the whole browser cache.